# How to write extensions for collection types

Tags: swift

```
extension Array {
    func sum() -> Int {
        var sum = 0
        for num in self {
            sum += num
        }
        return sum
    }
}

[1,2,3].sum()
```

This code shows what I would like to do. Though i get an error on the this line: `sum += num`. The error i get is: `Could not find an overload for '+=' that accepts the supplied arguments`.

I assume the error has something to do with the fact that Array can contain lots of different types, not just Int, so it's bugging out. But how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that's needed is an explicit cast to `Int`:

```
extension Array {
    func Sum() -> Int {
        var sum = 0

        for num in self {
            sum += (num as Int)
        }

        return sum
    }
}

println([1,2,3].Sum()) //6
```

Comment: Awesome. You're awesome.

Comment: This is a bit unfortunate, since it will still autocomplete for non-Int arrays, but will crash if you use it on them. Works fine for Int arrays though.

Comment: I'm wondering how long it will take before people start writing their own collection classes.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't currently a way to extend only a particular type of `Array` (`Array<Int>` in this case). That'd be a great request to file at bugreport.apple.com

In the meantime you can do this (not in an extension):

```
func sum(ints:Int[]) -> Int {
    return ints.reduce(0, +)
}
```

Comment: +1 for reduce. BTW did you find this through experimentation or are there docs on the Array type somewhere?

Comment: You can command-click on Array in Xcode to see a generated "header" for it

Comment: Ahhh, perfect, surprised I didn't know that yet. Thanks!